# How to display PDF document in .NET MVC using itext 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext, itext7

I am writing a .NET mvc web app that would automate working with tons of pdf forms.

For that, I need to be able to show PDF on the web app as a partial view. Fill it up from the database, make some editions and save/close it. 

How can I achieve that by using iText?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iText is a pdf manipulation library.
It can assist in two main domains:

- extracting data from a pdf
- generating pdf documents

iText does not enable you to view/render pdf documents.

Comment: is there any documentation on how to work with iText7 on ASP.NET? Right now, I can't even find how to automatically open a file after filled up.

Comment: iText does not automatically open the file after you're done working with it. iText is a pdf manipulation library, not a command shell.

Comment: how come in description for iTextSharp in NuGet it says iText7 "serve dynamically generated or manipulated PDF documents to a web browser"

Comment: Because iText does enable you to generate pdfs in a dynamic manner.
For instance, an airline-company can use iText to automatically generate boarding passes (in pdf format), and store them on their server. A dynamic webpage can then contain a button that allows the end-user to download these documents.

But iText is not to be confused with a pdf-reader (like Adobe).

Comment: thanks for explanation! Is there at least save method?

Comment: Please, check out the tutorials on the itext webpage. Of course it is possible to store a pdf. And if you approve of my answer, mark it as such.

Comment: not just store. The scenario is the following: I show a pdf as a part of a webpage. Now I want my user to be able to edit it from the page and then save the updates back to the database on a button click on the page.  I couldn't find proper documentation on .NET. Appreciate if you could share.

Comment: For iText7, the idea is that you create a PdfDocument instance based on a combination of a PdfReader and/or PdfWriter. Depending on which you supply, you have a document you can only read, only write to, or read/write. Look at the API pages to see what the constructors are for PdfReader and PdfWriter.